# Unable to receive email using Siteground and Heroku

Tags: dns, heroku

I'm having trouble setting up my email account. Specifically, my email account can send emails but cannot receive emails.
Here's the setup:

- I use Siteground for web hosting which includes my email account at my domain (umpirereporting.com)
- My application is deployed to Heroku
- Heroku has been set up to use PointDNS so that when I enter my domain name it loads the app at Heroku rather than looking on Siteground

I can send email from my email account using Siteground's webmail. But I cannot receive email. I've tried:

- Sending email from my personal Gmail account to this umpirereporting.com account
- Sending email from this email to this email (sending to itself)
- Checking my domain on mxtoolbox. There are a few errors but I don't know what they mean.

I've read a few questions and articles about setting MX records but I'm lost as to what I should be doing and where I should be doing it (Siteground or PointDNS or somewhere else).

How can I configure this email address to receive emails?

Comment: Who is your domain registrar?  What are the NS records set to at your domain registrar?   What does Siteground say your MX records should be?

Comment: My domain registrar is Hostgator. The NS records are set to the Siteground name servers. Siteground says the MX records should be "mx10.mailspamprotection.com" and that is what they are set to.

Comment: `dig NS umpirereporting.com` reports the NS servers are at `pointhq.com`.   Check that you are looking at hostgator for the NS records, not at siteground.  `dig MX umpirereporting.com` says you have no MX records set.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'll give that a try. Also I'm not sure why this question was put on hold as I thought it was clear what I was asking for.

Comment: You hadn't provided enough information to answer the question.  Now that you have, it appears that it is due to confusion over your MX records and I would close it as specific to one site.